# how to save sitecore webpage in html file on local disk or server

Tags: html, http-status-code-404, sitecore

```
WebRequest mywebReq ;
WebResponse mywebResp ;
StreamReader sr ;
string strHTML ;
StreamWriter sw;
mywebReq = WebRequest.Create("http://domain/sitecore/content/test/page10.aspx");
mywebResp = mywebReq.GetResponse();
sr = new StreamReader(mywebResp.GetResponseStream());
strHTML = sr.ReadToEnd();
sw = File.CreateText(Server.MapPath("hello.html"));
sw.WriteLine(strHTML);
sw.Close();
```

Hi ,

I want to save sitecore .aspx page into html file on local disk , but i am getting exception. But if i use any other webpage example(google.com) it works fine.

The exception :

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
HResult=-2146233079
Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Source=System
StackTrace:
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
   at BlueDiamond.addmodule.btnSubmit(Object sender, EventArgs e) in  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\STGLocal\Website\addmodule.aspx.cs:line 97
```

InnerException:

Any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exception? Stack trace? Which statement causes the exception? Lots of information missing here.

Comment: System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
       at test.addmodule.btnSubmit(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\STGLocal\Website\addmodule.aspx.cs:line 97
  InnerException:

Comment: You know what a 404 error is, right?  Page not found.

Comment: @JimGarrison , i know what  404 error mean, but i think you haven't read my question properly, i said that the problem is only when using Sitecore page , it is working fine when i am using other webpage.(eg. google.com). And -2 only for not adding sitecore tag

Comment: The server is returning 404. Either you have the URL wrong or there is a problem on the server. The fact that you can get to other pages just shows your network is working, but nothing about your specific problem.

Comment: my url http://domain/sitecore/content/test/page10.aspx is working fine when i am using in browser directly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40771/discussion-between-sam-and-jim-garrison)

Comment: So does the server differentiate based on user-agent?  It may not like the user-agent header sent by your code.  The only way to debug this is to see what happens at the protocol level when you use a browser (use Firebug or equivalent tools for Chrome/IE) and Wireshark when tracing your app.

Comment: Are you running this code locally or from your server? Is the site running Sitecore local or on a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you haven't published your page in Sitecore. If you browse to domain/sitecore/content/test/page10.aspx?sc_mode=normal, do you see the page then? If not publish the page (and the test page, templates and all other dependencies).

Comment: i figured this out yesterday, and it was same problem as mentioned by you .

Answer (score 0):

Jim, 
you can try some examples from the HTMLAgility pack. 
it's included in sitecore and handles this scenario perfectly.
here is an example:
http://blog.abodit.com/2010/03/a-simple-web-crawler-in-c-using-htmlagilitypack/